# Using SD.remove() and SD library in Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I'm building a program which takes 10 measurements of an analog voltage on `pin0` and is printing it to a log file. The issue I'm running into comes when I try to ensure that the file is blank. I am using `SD.remove()` in order to remove a previous logfile. When I do this, the new log file is never actually written to. When I remove the call to `SD.remove()`, the program works correctly. Is this some known bug in the SD library or is there some sneaky way around this?

The code is below.

```
#include <SD.h>
#define OUTPUT_PIN 9 //Using SparkFun MP3 shield
#define DEFAULT_OUTPUT 10
#define VOLTAGE_REF (5)

//Reads a voltage on pin0. by default, the reference voltage is set to 5 V, but
//it can be changed by changing VOLTAGE_REF.

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Program Initialized");

    pinMode(DEFAULT_OUTPUT ,OUTPUT); //Needs to be on to use the library
    pinMode(0, INPUT);

    if (!SD.begin(OUTPUT_PIN)) {
        //init error
        Serial.println("Error initializing SD card. Reset the Arduino and try again");
        return;
    }

    Serial.println("Card sucessfully initialized");

    if (SD.exists("LOGFILE.LOG") {
        SD.remove("LOGFILE.LOG"); //We don't want to use the same file <<THIS IS THE BUG?
    }

    delay(10); //Make sure changes are applied

    File logFile = SD.open("ANALOG.LOG", FILE_WRITE); //Create a new one every time
    if (!SD.exists("LOGFILE.LOG")) {
        Serial.println("There was some error making a new instance of the logfile?");
        delay(1000);
        SD.open("ANALOG.LOG", FILE_WRITE);
    }
    int i;

    if (logFile) {
        for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
            int j = 0;
            char str[64];

            Serial.print("Reading analog sensor value");
            for(j=0;j<=i;j++) {
                Serial.print(".");
            }
            Serial.println();

            logFile.print("Read #");
            logFile.print(i+1);
            logFile.print(" : ");
            logFile.print(doVoltageRead(0));
             unsigned char l = logFile.println(" V");
             if (!l)
                 Serial.println("No data written");
             delay(500);
        }
        Serial.println("Done.");
        logFile.close(); //Close the logfile
        Serial.println("Data sucessfully written");
    }
    else {
        //Couldn't create file
        Serial.println("There was an error creating the logfile");
    }
}

void loop() {
    //We don't really need to do anything here
}

float doVoltageRead(int pin) {
    int voltageRead = analogRead(pin);
    double divisor = (voltageRead * 0.00097752);
    float finalVoltage =(VOLTAGE_REF * divisor);
    Serial.println(finalVoltage);
    return finalVoltage;
}
```

Comment: What SD card are you using? For instance, SD or SDHC? Capacity? Brand (e.g. SanDisk)?

Comment: I am using a Sandisk brand microSD 2gb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the source of the error. When I called `if(SD.exists())` after opening a new logfile, the library didn't like that. I am assuming `SD.exists()` just checks if the address or object returned by open is NULL. However, calling it when the file is already open would cause some strange behaviors. After removing that call inside open, all is well. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

So.. First you see if LOGFILE.LOG exists, if it does you delete ANALOG.LOG. Then you create ANALOG.LOG. After that you check if LOGFILE.LOG exists. If it doesn't, you print an error and open ANALOG.LOG.

What exactly is the purpose of LOGFILE.LOG? Shouldn't you just change LOGFILE to ANALOG?

Comment: Good catch, I actually "Removed" the incorrect file in the code I had uploaded here.